# where's the LaTeX love gone?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, latex

A few sites across the network where we used to have LaTeX enabled, aren't displaying LaTeX currently:

- economics: https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/1106/104
- maths: [Absolute maximum value of $\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)$ in $[0,\frac{3\pi}{2}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119496/8572)

Ah, I'm in London, Europe: just in case this is a local CDN issue. Seeing it with Firefox & with a Google Chrome clone (SRWare Iron), on different PCs. I'm getting a timeout on cdn.mathjax.org

The site [DownForEveryoneOrJustMe.com reports that mathjax.org is down for them too](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/mathjax.org).

Comment: This looks like a problem with MathJax's CDN; the request to `http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML` is giving me (London, UK) a `504 Gateway Time-out`

Comment: @Matt: Same here in Vienna, Austria.

Comment: @Matt: Ditto here in Helsinki, Finland.  Ps. `host cdn.mathjax.org` says `cdn.mathjax.org is an alias for d3eoax9i5htok0.cloudfront.net.` for me, and lists 8 IPs in the `205.251.219.*` range.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard thanks - I've now incorporated that into the question

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be fixed now.. (It wasn't working for me--Mumbai, India--either)